# How to pass data from one controller action to another via POST

Tags: php, yii2

I wish to send a POST request from an action of a controller to an action of another controller. In the destination controller action , I am accessing POST data as `Yii::$app->request->post()`
I wish to modify this variable from another controller based on my need.

Please note that I do not want to use $_GET or it's Yii equivalent.

Comment: This approach sounds some kind of dirty to me. 
Antoher way could be, that you extract the functionality from the controller, you want to post to, into a service. Then you can use this service in both Controllers to modify your variable.

Comment: I think you have to use ajax to achieve above

Answer (score 1):

Like i wrote it in the comment, this would'nt be my prefered approach, but there is a function for that:

```
Yii::$app->runAction('yourController/yourAction', [$yourParameters]);
```

Comment: I think the parameters in $yourParameters are not sent via POST, they're sent as GET parameter. I need to send POST variables

Comment: making a curl-request to your desired action would work, i guess. 
But guy... this is really hard stuff :D

Comment: try it with runAction approach without parameters! You are not creating a new Request, so the POST-Variables of  "Yii::$app->request" should be available in your second controller, too!

Comment: I read about cURL approach somewhere and indeed it is a cumbersome process :P . I tried overwriting the $_POST variable and it seems to be working. Now the problem is when I access the posted data using $_POST in the destination controller, then I am able to see the new posted content, but using `Yii::$app->request->post()` gives only the originally posted content

Comment: theoretically you can overwrite the post-params with:
\Yii::$app->request->setBodyParams($yourParameters); before calling $app->runAction()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?= Html::a('Link Text', ['controller/action'], [
    'data'=>[
        'method' => 'post',
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to submit this?',
        'params'=>['id' => 21, 'val2' => true],
    ]
]) ?>
```

Adjust your values accordingly. The `confirm` is optional. Remove it if you don't want to confirm the user action.

Comment: But this can be done in the view file, right? The situation here is that I have a view file that a controller renders. There is a form whose data gets posted to the controller. Now in this controller #1 I want to perform some actions and add few more parameters to my $_POST variable and then call controller #2, where in using this updated $_POST I want to perform some other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Use following way

```
Yii::$app->request->setBodyParams(['message' => $message, 
                                   'toUserID' => $userID,
                                   'fromUserID'=>$this->userDetails->userid]);
Yii::$app->runAction('/chat/send-message');
```